# How do I get a comma-separated list of attributes from "rust - attribute macro"?

Tags: rust

With an attribute macro declared like this:

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn my_custom_attribute(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {}
```

If I use the attribute macro like this

```
#[my_custom_attribute(GET, ",_,_,", 33)]
fn my_function(a: u32) {
    println!("why..? {}", a);
}
```

How can I get the data for `"GET"`, `"\,\_\,\_\,"`, and `33` inside `my_custom_attribute`?

Comment: What do you have in `attr` argument? It should be almost exactly what you want (just with extra commas), you have something else there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn) is the most popular solution for parsing proc-macro input.

If your macro input has a standard structure, you can define a type with that structure, like this:

```rust
use syn::{
    parse::{Parse, ParseStream},
    Ident, LitInt, LitStr, Token,
};

struct Input {
    arg1: Ident,        // Ident parses an identifier
    _comma1: Token![,], // Token![,] parses a comma
    arg2: LitStr        // LitStr parses a string literal
    _comma2: Token![,],
    arg3: LitInt,       // LitInt parses an integer literal
}

impl Parse for Input {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream<'_>) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        Ok(Input {
            arg1: input.parse()?,
            _comma1: input.parse()?,
            arg2: input.parse()?,
            _comma2: input.parse()?,
            arg3: input.parse()?,
        })
    }
}
```

Then you use [`syn::parse_macro_input`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/macro.parse_macro_input.html) to parse the `TokenStream` into your struct:

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn my_custom_attribute(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = syn::parse_macro_input!(attr as Input);

    // Process `input` as necessary
}
```